# Inertia scrolling algorithm frame independant - predict end position

Tags: ios, algorithm, math, uiscrollview, physics

I have successfully implemented my scrolling algorithm by doing the following: when the user release the finger, I save the current speed, and then, every frame, I apply the following friction formula `speed *= pow(friction, dt)`, where friction is a value between 0 and 1 and `dt` is the time since the last frame.  I then stop updates when this is sufficiently close to zero.

But, I want to know where the scroll will end up at the time the finger is released, because I want to adjust it so the scroll will end up centered on an item.

It's very similar to the function scrollViewWillEndDragging(scrollView:withVelocity:targetContentOffset:) of UIScrollView

To summarize, I am looking for a formula that translate initial speed to  total delta movement and the reverse formula delta movement to speed.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your velocity is described by formula

```
V = V0 * Exp(- k * t)
```

(To ensure, show speed for moments 0, dt, 2dt, 3dt)

where V0 is starting velocity, k is friction coefficient (depending on your `friction`)
To find distance, we have to integrate velocity ([link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integral%28a*exp%28-k*t%29*dt%29%2C%20t%3D0..infinity))

```
S = Integral[0..Infinity] (V * dt) = V0 / k
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, let's say my friction coefficient is 0.2, if my speed is 10, my total distance is 50? If it's that, it's not the case. I can give you a sample: -0.0197985639287468 V0 result in -0.0124204164005296 distance. -1.55563096586029 V0 result in -0.977623871046036 displacement.

Comment: My friction coefficient depends on yours one, but  it is not equal. To find dependence, provide speed values for moments 0, dt, 2dt, 3dt...

Comment: @Naluh: what dt are you using?

Comment: the dt is the time between frame, it's 0.016 most of the time but it can be longer if the gpu takes more time to calculate the frame.